# How do I run a Docker container as a persistent server?

Tags: java, python, docker, server

I have two things:

1. A Java server API that receives a file
2. A Python script I need to be able to feed the received file into

I want to be able to run my Python script in multiple Docker containers that listen for a file input, so I can run the script on multiple files at the same time. How can I containerise my script so it runs as a small persistent server? At the moment I have a container that just runs the script and then immediately exits.

So in a nutshell I need this structure:
File -> Java API -> Containerised Python script running on a port

I'm new to the concept and didn't understand the Docker documentation and hoped some kind soul could simplify it for me. Thank you

Comment: Considered doing this as a rest service?

Comment: The other plausible option is to install Python and the script into the Java image, and then just run it as a normal subprocess.

Answer (score -1):

Create one Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.8.2-buster
USER root
RUN mkdir -p '/script'
WORKDIR script
COPY requirements.txt /script
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "your_script.py" ]
```

Then build it and run it as daemon.

```
docker build -t myscript .
docker run -d --name script -v $(pwd):/script -p <local_port:port_inside_container> myscript
```

Comment: The container will still exit as soon as `your_script.py` completes.